# How can I display a dialog box that contains the properties of an X.509 certificate?

Tags: java, x509certificate

I want to display dialog box that contains properties of an X509 Cert. That box includes three tabs:

1. General
2. Details
3. Certification path

As in this image.

[image: X509 cert. dialog]

With C# i use a statement:

```
X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate(X509Certificate2 cert);
```

But with Java, I can't find similar statement!

How can I display a dialog box that contains the properties of an X.509 certificate?

Comment: *"Sr about my English!"*  Don't you think it would make sense to better communicate with other people who do not understand English well, by spelling *all 5* letters of 'sorry'?  As an aside, I would let 'sory' pass without comment, but 'sr' just seems lazy.

Comment: What happens with `Desktop.getDesktop().open("x509.cer");`?

Comment: my certs are in my token, i only get them in my code, can not extract to my destop. So your statement can't use, i think that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could track, the .NET will use following function to display the cert information:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
internal class CRYPTUI_VIEWCERTIFICATE_STRUCTW
{
    internal uint dwSize;
    internal IntPtr hwndParent;
    internal uint dwFlags;
    internal string szTitle;
    internal IntPtr pCertContext;
    internal IntPtr rgszPurposes;
    internal uint cPurposes;
    internal IntPtr pCryptProviderData;
    internal bool fpCryptProviderDataTrustedUsage;
    internal uint idxSigner;
    internal uint idxCert;
    internal bool fCounterSigner;
    internal uint idxCounterSigner;
    internal uint cStores;
    internal IntPtr rghStores;
    internal uint cPropSheetPages;
    internal IntPtr rgPropSheetPages;
    internal uint nStartPage;
    public CRYPTUI_VIEWCERTIFICATE_STRUCTW();
}

[DllImport("cryptui.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
internal static extern bool CryptUIDlgViewCertificateW(
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] CRYPTUI_VIEWCERTIFICATE_STRUCTW ViewInfo, 
    [In, Out] IntPtr pfPropertiesChanged);
```

I am not a java expert, and unsure how is it possible to call Windows functions from java, but there must be a way. Look at MSDN for [CryptUIDlgViewCertificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, and you will know the details

Comment: It's a JNI programming project.