# Functionality like .NET X509Certificate2UI in java

Tags: java, .net, applet, japplet

Is there a equivalent of the `X509Certificate2UI` class in java or is there a way I can call it from java code? I want my client to choose a certificate from a java applet. I am currently    enumerating the certificates manually with the MSCAPI provider and transfer the results (aliasses/thumbprints) to a html selectbox where the user can select the certificate. It would be much nicer if the user can choose it from a (sort of) native windows dialog.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display a dialog box that contains the properties of an X.509 certificate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330796/how-can-i-display-a-dialog-box-that-contains-the-properties-of-an-x-509-certific)

Comment: You are able to call native C/C++ libraries with JNA https://github.com/twall/jna Calling c# is not this easy...

Comment: @Lonzak: I do not think it is a duplicate, but your idea of using JNA I will give a try.